# Api and application's container both are listening on 8080

Tags: containers

We have a scenerio as we have a application which has three components like

1. Application Solution
2. API Solution
3. Postgres Database

And we have to configure all this components using docker as

- Container 1 - Application Solution
- Container 2 - API Solution

Database on Particular Server and we need to create a solution to connect all this to run the application as
Our Application is Connected to API using localhost on some port and our api is connected to database on some server xyz so using this we have to connect application container with API and API with database on server so we need a solution for this scenerio
Application --> API --> Database

We are also facing a major issue with the ports of container as the host for api and application's container are listening on 8080 only we have nothing specific in our code where we have defined port as 8080 but API container and Web container internally is running on 8080 only so for that reason only our connection between the container is not building.

we are using the compose file as below -

```
version: '3.8'
 
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: energy_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: energyEfficiencydb
  api:
    image: energyefficiencyapi
    container_name: energyefficiencyapi
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__dev=http://database:5432
 
  website:
    image: energyefficiencyportal
    container_name: energyefficiencyportal
    ports: 
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://api:8082
    depends_on:
      - api
      - database
```

Issue: Issue with the ports of container as the host for api and application's both container are listening on 8080 only. and we have nothing specific or defined port as 8080 in both API container and Web container but internally are running on 8080, so for that reason our connection between the container is not building/working. how we assign different port to both container

Comment: So run them on different ports?

Comment: You say you are facing major issues, but you are not telling us about your issues. This makes understand your issues too difficult for most users. You are also not asking any specific questions. People may not know how and what to respond.

Comment: issue with the ports of container as the host for api and application's container are listening on 8080 only. and we have nothing specific in our code where we have defined port as 8080 but both API container and Web container internally  are running on 8080, so for that reason only our connection between the container is not building. how we assign different port to both container

Comment: Yes we want to run api and application's container on different port. but how ?

Comment: @ChetanBhatt That sounds like an extraordinary setup. Usually, each container is given its own IP address inside the docker network and therefore there aren't any issues with both applications using the same port. Maybe you need to backtrack and examine your problem more closely.

Comment: @ChetanBhatt selecting a differnt port to listen on is application specific. Without knowing anything about the software and/or the programming language you are using. Nobody will be able to tell you how to select a different port.